# Purpose of casting like this?

Tags: java

Is there any purpose to casting like this?

Sorry guys it seems my code stripping caused some confusing. Full method goes like this:

```
public String foo() {
    Object obj = getAnObject(); //returns various objects that all extend Object
    A aVar = null;

    if(!(obj instanceof A)) { return null; }

    if(object != null)
        aVar = (A) object; //Cast in question since instanceof check is done

    Object obj1 = ((aVar != null) ? aVar : new A());
    sendToJSPasJSON(obj1);

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Legacy code, maybe. Otherwise, it's nonsense.

Comment: Uugh. No. The method returns `void`. Unless `getAnObject` mutates the instance somehow, this has **no** purpose and should be nuked from orbit.

Comment: Yep, makes no sense. Since your method does not return or mutate anything (at least nothing obvious) it may be that you stripped too much.

Comment: @atamanroman: We don't *know* `getAnObject` doesn't mutate something, and that `new B` doesn't have side-effects. You'd sure hope they wouldn't, but... :-)

Comment: As long as getAnObject() has no side-effects and neither does the constructor call `new B()` then this code is a no-op.  (Assuming you have given us the whole method.)

Comment: @Paul: Dmitry caught us all out -- it's not *quite* a no-op without side effects. But: Ugh. :-)

Comment: @T.J.Crowder yeah that's why I edited "_(at least nothing obvious)_" in my comment ;)

Comment: @atamanroman Sorry, this is like a scale down of what I saw; only thing missing is that the object gets sent as a JSON to jsp. No mutating is done at all.

Comment: @MichaelAu: And does it rely on the `ClassCastException`, or does `getAnObject` **always** return something that can be cast to `A`?

Comment: @ T.J Crowder I might've scaled down too much, I'll edit original.

Comment: @MichaelAu I would suggest to make this method `public void` and when you need to quit just write `return;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only reason I can think of is to check that `obj` is an object of class `A` (and to throw a `ClassCastException` if it is not).
But this may be done using `instanceof`:

```
if (!(obj instanceof A)) {
    // do something (throw an exception)
}
```

Unless throwing an exception if `getAnObject` returns something that can't be cast to `A` is significant, the code you wrote may be simplified to:

```
Object obj = getAnObject();
Object obj1 = ((obj != null) ? obj : new B());
```

Or even

```
if (getAnObject() != null) {
    new B();
}
```

But it's extremely bad form for a constructor to have side-effects, which would be the only reason for `new B()` if the object isn't `null`.

Comment: I think I'll just use instanceof and remove the casting.

Comment: Actually the updated code variant clarifies question.
Java compiler will force you to put explicit class casting (if I remember well). It is a syntactic Java rule (all casts should be explicit even when class is 100% known to be correct).